# Increment value and save back to the file

Tags: json, increment, jq

I have a simple JSON file like this,

```
{

...
"version": "2.1.0",
"buildNumber": 83

}
```

I want to simply increment the buildNumber by one in the file. Rest of the content should remain as is.

What I have come up with so far is bellow.

```
jq -e '.buildNumber + 1' 'package.json' > 'package.json.tmp' && cp 'package.json.tmp' 'package.json'
```

But after running the script I'm only left with the updated value in the package.json file, which is just 84. The rest of the content is gone. How do I fix this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just put the two commands as bellow in two lines and it worked just as I wanted.

```
jq '.buildNumber += 1' 'package.json' > 'package.json.tmp'
cp 'package.json.tmp' 'package.json'
```

Comment: A safer variation would be along the lines of: `mv package.json package.json.bak && jq ... < package.json.bak > package.json`; that way, the original file contents should not be lost under any circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

First, the filter to use is:

```
.buildNumber += 1
```

Second, as you evidently realize, it would be unwise to use > to overwrite the file.  One option to consider if it’s admissible would be to use coreutil’s `sponge`. Another would be to rename the input file first.

Comment: I just found out about jq a couple of hours ago and I'm not quite familiar with bash every since I learned the basics of it like 8 years ago. I was under the impression that by doing `jq '.buildNumber + 1' 'package.json'` the full contents of the file would be in memory including the modification. And so I was simply writing that content to a temp file and the evidently replacing the original file with the temp file contents. Am I understanding how jq works wrong?

Comment: uYes, that is incorrect. As you can easily check, .buildnumber + 1 adds 1 to .buildnumber, yielding an integer.

Comment: So what I'm passing on to the package.json.temp file is simply that value, which in this case just 84. So if I use `curl` and read the full content of the file and then do `jq '.buildNumber += 1' 'package.json'` and then carry on as is, that would give me the ouput I'm expecting yes?